# Add JavaScript default language hint to [mongo-shell] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

My [mongo-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-shell) code examples are not syntax highlighted. It seems that syntax highlight language is identified by question tags.

The MongoDB shell is built on a JavaScript execution engine (V8). Although MongoDB provides some enhancements that are not pure JavaScript, JavaScript syntax highlighting would improve question/answer readability.

The default/specific language hint is supposed to be listed on the tag info wiki page below the edit and history links, but it is not visible for me so I can't verify that it does not already exist.

Comment: I see that this feature request completely fell through the cracks. I edited it to clarify which tags you want to be modified, which will also bump it to hopefully get some more eyes on it. If some modicum of consensus can be reached, even so much as another user active in these tags agreeing, then I can make this happen. I don't know anything about these technologies myself, so I'm not comfortable doing it without some show of support.

Comment: @CodyGray Is this still necessary I wonder? If I look at for example this question about mongoshell, there is syntax highlighting going on without any help as far as I can tell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568752/mongo-shell-insert-statement-for-array-of-objects-failing-validation

Comment: Ah, [[tag:mongodb]] has JS syntax highlighting, so that's why the post you linked is getting highlighted. It wasn't entirely clear to me in the original feature request whether he was requesting syntax highlighting for both tags, or just the one, so I guessed. I should have checked to see what was actually active. Not sure if it's necessary to have it for [[tag:mongo-shell]] or not. @gimby

Comment: @CodyGray it can't hurt, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004242/read-image-file-into-a-mongodb-documents-binary-field-via-mongo-shell-script). But usually people tag mongodb anyway, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It actually *can* hurt, because it can lead to conflicts. But in this case...yeah. [All but 5 people tag with \[mongodb\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-shell+-mongodb) :-) Probably should just mark this as completed. @gimby